# iPhone 4 "A Series" battery?

Tags: iphone, battery

I was just about to order a replacement for my iphone 4, when I noticed there are apparently two different types. Both are claimed to be genuine apple batteries, however [one](http://www.mytrendyphone.co.uk/shop/apple-iphone-4-32731p.html) costs nearly 10GBP more than the [other](http://www.mytrendyphone.co.uk/shop/apple-iphone-4-33359p.html). The only difference I can tell is that one of them is called *"iPhone 4 Battery **A Series**"*

Anyone has an idea what the difference might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gotten an answer from the seller, who states that they are both the same. Hm, price targeting?